# Multiple implicit rules for order-only prerequisites

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to make an order-only prerequisite to make sure a build directory exists before outputting files.  According to the [GNU Make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html):

> you may still declare multiple lines of prerequisites for the same target: they are appended appropriately (normal prerequisites are appended to the list of normal prerequisites; order-only prerequisites are appended to the list of order-only prerequisites).

So I expect this should work:

```
BUILDDIR:=build

all: $(BUILDDIR)/test.o
clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILDDIR)

$(BUILDDIR):
    mkdir -p $(@)

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: | $(BUILDDIR)
$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: %.c
    gcc -o $@ -c $<
```

But it does not, failing to create the directory.  However, when I put the rule on a single line, it does work:

```
$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: %.c | $(BUILDDIR)
```

In this simple example, it doesn't matter, but I need to make multiple prerequisite lists like this for my more complicated makefile, and the manual makes it sounds like it should work.  How can I accomplish this?

In case it matters:

```
$ make -v
GNU Make 3.81
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An implicit rule with no recipes is dropped during [implicit rule search](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rule-Search.html), its only purpose is to [cancel](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html) any previously defined identical rule. This means that the line `$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: | $(BUILDDIR)` essentially has no effect.

Since you already have a list of prerequisites you can use regular and static pattern rules instead:

```
BUILDDIR := build
OBJS     := $(BUILDDIR)/test.o

all: $(OBJS)
clean:
    $(RM) -r $(BUILDDIR)

$(BUILDDIR):
    mkdir -p $@

$(OBJS): | $(BUILDDIR)
$(OBJS): $(BUILDDIR)/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $<
```